# How to have Page Navigation programmatically in ReportViewer?

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

I'm writing a report in ASP.NET using Reporting Services. I want to hide the Toolbar of the ReportViewer and have my own "Next Page" and "Previous Page" buttons. Is there a way to programmatically navigate through ReportViewer pages? Does it have methods such as "NextPage" and "PreviousPage"?

Comment: Have you tried the [CurrentPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.reportviewer.currentpage%28v=vs.100%29) property?

Answer (score 2):

If you hide the toolbar and have your own controls for page navigation you could set the ReportViewer's [CurrentPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.reportviewer.currentpage%28v=vs.100%29) property in your code.

Answer (score 1):

I just thought I'd add to this as I've been doing similar things and have built a little set of JavaScript (using JQuery) functions where you can pass the ReportViewerID and it'll allow you to add next, previous, first last and so on to your own custom toolbar buttons. Just hide the toolbar using the ReportViewer_HideToolbar function on document ready. Thought it was worth sharing as I couldn't find anything on this when searching for hours yesterday. Even if it's just a starting point for someone, atleast it's that bit closer and of help :-)

p.s. I'm using ReportViewer 10, others may be different and not work.

```
function ReportViewer_FirstPage(ReportViewerID) {
    var ReportViewer = $("span[id$='" + ReportViewerID + "_ReportViewer'")
    ReportViewer.find("input[title='First Page']").first().click()
}

function ReportViewer_NextPage(ReportViewerID) {
    var ReportViewer = $("span[id$='" + ReportViewerID + "_ReportViewer'")
    ReportViewer.find("input[title='Next Page']").first().click()
}


function ReportViewer_PreviousPage(ReportViewerID) {
    var ReportViewer = $("span[id$='" + ReportViewerID + "_ReportViewer'")
    ReportViewer.find("input[title='Previous Page']").first().click()
}

function ReportViewer_LastPage(ReportViewerID) {
    var ReportViewer = $("span[id$='" + ReportViewerID + "_ReportViewer'")
    ReportViewer.find("input[title='Last Page']").first().click()
}

var tReportViewerLastFindText = ""
function ReportViewer_Set_SearchText(ReportViewerID, tText) {
    var ReportViewer = $("div[id$='MainPlaceHolder_" + ReportViewerID + "'")
    ReportViewer.find("input[title='Find Text in Report']").val(tText)
    var m_reportViewer = $find($(ReportViewer).attr('id'))
    if (tReportViewerLastFindText != tText) {
        m_reportViewer.find(tText)
        tReportViewerLastFindText = tText
    } else {
        m_reportViewer.findNext()
    }
}

function ReportViewer_Set_PageNumber(ReportViewerID, tPageNumber) {
    var ReportViewer = $("span[id$='" + ReportViewerID + "_ReportViewer'")
    var CurrentPage = ReportViewer.find("input[title='Current Page']")
    $(CurrentPage).val(tPageNumber)
    __doPostBack(CurrentPage.attr("name"), '')
}

function ReportViewer_Print(ReportViewerID) {
    var ReportViewer = $("div[id$='MainPlaceHolder_" + ReportViewerID + "'")
    var m_reportViewer = $find($(ReportViewer).attr('id'))
    m_reportViewer.invokePrintDialog()
}

function ReportViewer_HideToolbar(ReportViewerID) {
    var ReportViewer = $("span[id$='" + ReportViewerID + "_ReportViewer'")
    $(ReportViewer).find("div[style$='toolbar_bk.png);']").hide()
}
```

Regards
Liam